# Amplify Developer Menu - how to disable it

Tags: aws-amplify

I installed an Amplify developer app on my phone, now I can't get rid of this.
It keeps popping up every time.
How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin:

```
val config = AmplifyConfiguration.builder(applicationContext).devMenuEnabled(false).build()
Amplify.configure(config, applicationContext)
```

Java:

```
Amplify.configure(AmplifyConfiguration.builder(getApplicationContext()).devMenuEnabled(false).build(), getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 2):

Java

structed

```
AmplifyConfiguration config = AmplifyConfiguration.builder(getApplicationContext())
.devMenuEnabled(false)
.build(),
getApplicationContext());
```

minified

```
AmplifyConfiguration config = AmplifyConfiguration.builder(getApplicationContext()).devMenuEnabled(false).build(), getApplicationContext());
```

Kotlin

structed

```
val config = AmplifyConfiguration.builder(applicationContext)
.devMenuEnabled(false)
.build()
Amplify.configure(config, applicationContext)
```

minified

```
val config = AmplifyConfiguration.builder(applicationContext).devMenuEnabled(false).build()Amplify.configure(config, applicationContext)
```